# Set property to empty - SAP CRM WebUI

Tags: properties, defaultifempty, sap-crm

I am new to SAP, and am encountering an issue I am not sure how to resolve.

I am setting a property to '' (empty), but it is not being displayed as such.

There is existing logic that sets specific fields to 'Display Only' when a checkbox is checked. I am working to extend this to clear any data that is within those fields. Due to how the original logic was implemented, this change is being handled in the "Get_..." method (may be moved to an event handler once I get it working).

Currently, the logic sets the property to be empty (I have confirmed this with debug); however, the webpage keeps the original value. A shortened outline of the code is below (all try catches, etc. removed to keep it short and simple):

```
DATA: current     TYPE REF TO if_bol_bo_property_access.
DATA: dref        TYPE REF TO data.

current = collection_wrapper->get_current( ).
dref = current->get_property( 'FIRSTNAME' ).


* If condition
DATA: copy          TYPE REF TO data.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:
      <nval> TYPE ANY,
      <oval> TYPE ANY.

ASSIGN dref->* TO <oval>.
CREATE DATA copy LIKE <oval>.

CLEAR value.

TRY.
    CALL METHOD if_bsp_model_util~convert_from_string
    EXPORTING
         data_ref       = copy
         value          = value
         attribute_path = attribute_path.
    CATCH cx_sy_conversion_error.
        RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_bsp_conv_failed
        EXPORTING
              name = 'FIRSTNAME'.
ENDTRY.

current->set_property_as_string(
          iv_attr_name = 'FIRSTNAME' 
          iv_value     = value ).

value = current->get_property_text( 'FIRSTNAME' ). "Check empty ''
```

Most of this was pulled from the 'Set_...' method. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the CRM browser autosaving before the case is complete. This causes the values to be rendered as though they are cached.

Note 2104051 resolves this.